# Wordpress .sub-menu different background image for each link

Tags: wordpress, dynamic, background-image

I have a bunch of images named after my pages in wordpress. Example:

- page name : heart-health
- image name : heart-health.png

My main menu has 1 sub-menu level and for each page name in a sub-level I would like to display the image as a background image set to the left. I have tried so many different ways but had no luck.

I know you can add custom text to the menu in the admin but I wish for it all to be done automatically.

I have found the start and end for sub level menu items in "nav-menu-template.php" & "class-wp-walker.php"

At the moment I just have the same picture showing on all sub menu items when you rollover but that is just using CSS.

```
.menu ul ul :hover > a{color:#000000;background-color: #eeeeee; background-image:url(images/menu-images/fruit.png); background-repeat:no-repeat;}
```

Any help or advice would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way to do it is via CSS.

For example

```
.menu ul ul .custom-class a { ... }
.menu ul ul .custom-class:hover a { ... }
```

You can set custom classes for each menu item in the WordPress menu management, just make sure the "CSS Classes" checkbox in "Screen Option" (top right of page) is checked.

Also, to make things easier, I would suggest making an image sprite of all the images you'll be using in the menu so that your CSS code is much simpler.

```
.menu ul ul a {
  background:url('/url-to-sprite.png') no-repeat 0px 0px;
}

.menu ul ul :hover a {
  background-position:-20px 0px;
}

.menu ul ul .custom-class a {
  background-position:0px -20px;
}

.menu ul ul .custom-class:hover a {
  background-position:-20px -20px;
}
```

Comment: you are an absolute star, didnt even know that option was there, had a play around with it and seems like all is well,
Also i used your idea for the css to keep it a bit more tidy :)